# Open URL in new browser tab when click on HTML button

Tags: html, web

I am designing a web site with CodeIgniter and I want to open some URL when user click on its buttons (URLs have to open in new tab).
I use this code and it works when you want to open URL in same tab, but I want the URL to open in a new tab. I don't want to use JavaScript function too.

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com'">Google</button>
```

Comment: You should use the <a/> tag instead and style it as a button.

Comment: basically, open an url on a new tab it's a user preference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could change your button to be an anchor...

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Then you could add styling to your anchor... if this is even required.

Comment: I think its the best way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<button type = "button" onclick = "location.href = window.open('link')"></button>
```